# Create pages automatically if they don't exist

Tags: pages, customization

I have a WPMU instance that works less like a network of blogs and more like a holistic application. I'm needing to do a check and see if 3 pages with the slugs 'home', 'login', and 'password' exist. If not, I need the system to generate them automatically. If it does, I need the system to ignore.

Right now I have the following code, and for some reason it is generating 5 posts each time a page is loaded. Anyone have advice on how I could better accomplish this?

```
function check_pages_live(){
        if(get_page_by_title( 'home', page ) != NULL) {
            create_pages_fly('home');
        }
        if(get_page_by_title( 'login', page ) != NULL) {
            create_pages_fly('login');
        }
        if(get_page_by_title( 'password', page ) != NULL) {
            create_pages_fly('password');
        }
    }
    add_action('init','check_pages_live');
    function create_pages_fly($pageName) {
        $createPage = array(
          'post_title'    => $pageName,
          'post_content'  => 'Starter content',
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_type'     => 'page',
          'post_name'     => $pageName
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $createPage );
    }
```

Comment: I would try `get_page_by_path`, since `get_page_by_title` can return an array, that's the only logical reason it is returning 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
if( get_page_by_title( 'home' ) == NULL )
    create_pages_fly( 'home' );
```

Your original `if` condition said if the page exists (does not equal NULL), then create the page. Also, the 2nd argument should be a string, though it doesn't really matter in this case since it'll just default to `'page'` anyway.

Comment: Doh! Can't believe I did that. Must have been a curse of staring at code for too long today. This is perfect. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 3):

Very handy function, I'll be adapting this for some of my work.  One minor enhancement I'd make to streamline it a bit more is to put the get_by_title() action into a function, so you can just call that on each page.

Ex:

```
function create_page_if_null($target) {
    if( get_page_by_title($target) == NULL ) {
        create_pages_fly($target);
    }
}

function check_pages_live(){
    create_page_if_null('about');
    create_page_if_null('contact-us');
    create_page_if_null('home');
    create_page_if_null('news');
    create_page_if_null('privacy');
}
```